# How to traverse a tree in Clojure while collecting the value from each node node?

Tags: clojure, tree, lisp

I want to create a function that collects the value from each node in a binary tree.  In the ClojureDocs, I found several functions for traversing a tree/graph, such as tree-seq, prewalk, and postwalk.

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/tree-seq

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/prewalk

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/postwalk

Can any of these be used to accumulate the value of nodes traversed?  As a Clojure newby, I don't see how to do it.  If you know how (in Clojure or similar Lispy language), please show me.  Ideally, your answer will be understandable by a Clojure newby;-)

My binary tree is represented with nodes like this: (value left-child right-child). For example:

> ( 2 (7 nil nil) (88 (5 nil nil) nil) )

From this example, I'd like the function to return (2 7 88 5).

NOTE: The traversal method isn't important.  I just want to learn a technique for collecting node values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, `tree-seq` will give you the node sequence (of a depth first walk). You can then do any other transformation on it, including `(map some-value-extractor-fn (tree-seq ...`  to get the values in each node. You just need to pick a tree representation and appropriate functions for that representation so `tree-seq` can know what is an internal node and what its children are. 
For instance, using your definition of the tree as a nested list:

### Nested list tree

The nodes where our tree could branch are lists, which we can identify using `list?`.Their children are the values following the first, i.e. their `rest`. So we can define the tree-seq using only standard functions:

```
(->> '( 2 (7 nil nil) (88 (5 nil nil) nil) )
     (tree-seq list? rest))
```

but this has a bit of garbage - each `nil` appears as a member of the seq, each value we're interested in appears both in its list node and as a member in itself and so on. We can clean this up with a `filter` or `remove` - for instance we can discard all the leaf values and take only internal nodes:

```
(->> '( 2 (7 nil nil) (88 (5 nil nil) nil) )
     (tree-seq list? rest)
     (filter list?))
;;=> ((2 (7 nil nil) (88 (5 nil nil) nil)) (7 nil nil) (88 (5 nil nil) nil) (5 nil nil))
```

and then just `map` `first` over those:

```
(->> '( 2 (7 nil nil) (88 (5 nil nil) nil) )
     (tree-seq list? rest)
     (filter list?)
     (map first)) ;;=>(2 7 88 5)
```

Alternatively we could try to discard internal and nil nodes of the tree, taking only leaves with a value:

```
(->> '( 2 (7 nil nil) (88 (5 nil nil) nil) )
     (tree-seq list? seq)
     (remove (some-fn list? nil?))) ;;=>(2 7 88 5)
```

Note that in this strategy I had to use `seq` rather than `rest`, as I want the first value in a list to also be a child of that node. `(some-fn list? nil?)` is a bit of higher order functions - it builds a function that checks if the input satisfies *either* of the predicates `list?` *or* `nil?` (or both).

### Nested map tree

If you want a maybe more general tree definition, where each node can contain multiple values plus a variable number of children, you can define your tree as nested maps: `{:value 2 :children [{:value 7} {:value 88 :children [{:value 5}]}]}`

In this case, looking at only the maps as nodes is generally simplest. Our possibly branching nodes are maps - check for that with `map?`. We stored their children in the key `:children`, which is a keyword and so is also a function. We use that function to get the children.

```
(->> {:value 2 :children [{:value 7} {:value 88 :children [{:value 5}]}]} 
     (tree-seq map? :children)) 
;;=> ({:value 2, :children [{:value 7} {:value 88, :children [{:value 5}]}]} {:value 7} {:value 88, :children [{:value 5}]} {:value 5})
```

and then you just need to `map` over the nodes to get the data you want out of them:

```
(->> {:value 2 :children [{:value 7} {:value 88 :children [{:value 5}]}] } 
     (tree-seq map? :children)
     (map :value)) ;;=> (2 7 88 5)
```

Comment: Wow.  Thanks for taking time to answer in such detail.  It'll take me a while to digest.  I'm glad to do it to learn Clojure better.

Answer (score 1):

for accumulating node values of a tree, i have a non-functional solution:

```
user> (def a (atom 0))
#'user/a
user> (dorun (clojure.walk/postwalk #(when (number? %) (swap! a (partial + %))) '( 2 (7 nil nil) (88 (5 nil nil) nil))))
nil
user> @a
102
```

Comment: This is interesting.  Thanks