# Clojure tree node based on depth

Tags: clojure, tree

I've been struggling with a recursion problem and I'm running out of ideas. Basically, I have a tree representation that looks like this:

```
{1 {:root nil} 2 {:root 1} 3 {:root 1} 4 {:root 2} 5 {:root 1} 6 {:root 4}}
```

And I have to build a new tree out of the last one which indicates parent/child relationship levels. A valid output would be:

```
{ 1 [3 1] 2 [1] 3 [] 4 [1] 5 [] 6 [] }
```

Where each node has an array of a count of items by level of relationship. So node 1 has 3 direct children (2 3 5) and one grandchild (4). Node 2 has only one child (4), node 4 has one direct child (6) and all the others are empty (have no children).

I found some questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30826516/how-to-traverse-a-tree-in-clojure-while-collecting-the-value-from-each-node-node) that actually helped but aren't exactly what I was looking for. I'm also new to function programming and any help is going to be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I understand your tree representation. What do `:root` and `:parent` keys stand for? I would expect to only find a direct parent for every node, why do you need an additional key?

Comment: It was a typo, the key is ":root". Every node has a reference to its parent (root) . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that there is an error in your sample output above and that it should really be:

```
{ 1 [3 1 1] 2 [1 1] 3 [] 4 [1] 5 [] 6 [] }
```

Your sample output did not account for the fact that 6 is a great-grandchild of 1 and a grandchild of 2.

I'll detail a solution here. We'll start out by writing a function which, given a tree and a vertex in that tree, calculates the path from that vertex to the top of the tree:

```
(defn path-to-top [tree v]
    (if (nil? v)
        '()
        (cons v (path-to-top tree (:root (get tree v))))))
```

Next up, let us write a function which takes such a path from the vertex to the top of the tree and associates with each vertex *on* the distance of that vertex from the starting vertex:

```
(defn steps-indexed-path
    ([upward-path steps]
        (if (= upward-path '())
            '()
            (cons [(first upward-path) steps] (steps-indexed-path (rest upward-path) (+ steps 1)))))
    ([upward-path]
        (steps-indexed-path upward-path 0)))
```

Where the first function returned a list of vertices, this function returns a list of vectors in which the first entry is a vertex and the second entry is the number of steps from the first vertex on the path to the given vertex.

Alright, when we apply this function to each of the vertices in the tree, we will have (in some nested form) for each vertex `v` and for each descendant `w` of `v` the data `[v <# steps from v to w>]`. For each of these data, we should add 1 to the `<# steps from v to w>` component of the vector associated with `v` in our final solution. Before we move to the vector stage, let us just associate levels with counts:

```
(defn count-descendants [tree]
    (let [markers (reduce concat '() (map steps-indexed-path (map (partial path-to-top tree) (keys tree))))]
        (reduce (fn [counter [vertex generation]] (assoc counter vertex (assoc (get counter vertex {}) generation (+ (get (get counter vertex {}) generation 0) 1)))) {} markers)))
```

This produces a `hash-map` whose keys are the vertices of `v` and such that the value corresponding to each vertex `v` is another `hash-map` in which the keys are the different possible generations of descendants of that vertex in the tree, and the values are the number of descendants at each generation.

All we have to do now is turn the output of the previous function into the format specified by you:

```
(defn sanitize-descendant-counts [association] 
    (let [max-depth (apply max (keys association))]
        (map (fn [i] (get association i 0)) (range 1 (+ max-depth 1)))))

(defn solve-problem [tree]
    (let [descendant-counts (count-descendants tree)]
        (apply merge (map (fn [v] (hash-map v (vec (sanitize-descendant-counts (get descendant-counts v))))) (keys descendant-counts)))))
```

This is what I get as output when I run this code on your example:

```
{1 [3 1 1], 4 [1], 6 [], 3 [], 2 [1 1], 5 []}
```

You can [access all the code here](https://gist.github.com/nkashy1/62dbd23f62b2a4d320bfaafce7385a32), including what you need to run on your example. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I will try to outline a possible approach, stressing the recursion core, and glossing over smaller details. There are quite a few of those smaller details, and some of them aren't exactly trivial, but they have nothing to do with the recursion itself, and would just clutter the answer.

Let's abstract from the details of your tree representation. Think about a tree as a collection of nodes, where each node may be either a leaf (no children,) or a branch otherwise. Assume we have two functions `branch?` and `children`. Either receives one parameter - a node. `branch?` is a predicate with an obvious meaning, `children` returns a sequence of children of the node. (It is the same contract as expected by `tree-seq` core function.) I leave it to you to code `branch?` and `children`. (You may want to change your tree representation to make it easier to code these functions.)

Let's try to create a function `levels` that given a node will return a sequence of number of descendants by levels - children, grandchildren and so on. So we would expect for your tree

```
(levels 1)
;; => (3 1 1)
(levels 2)
;; => (1 1)
```

(You got a typo, by the way. Node 1 has a grand-grandchild - it's 6)

And here's the core - `levels`:

```
(defn levels
  [node]
  (if (branch? node)
    (cons (count (children node)) (sum-up-levels (map levels (children node))))
    []))
```

This is the meat of the recursion. The *base case* is the leaf - when `branch?` returns `false` we know there are no children, so the levels are empty - `[]`. Otherwise, we count the children and `cons` that number (i.e. add to the list) of the *summed up* levels below. Summing up means summing the numbers by levels - total number of children, then total number of grandchildren and so on. And here we have the recursion - we descend down to the children, invoking `levels` recursively for every child using `map`.

The `sum-up-levels` function is a bit annoying to code. I am leaving so much for you to fill in that I'd probably just give my code of it here (certainly not the shortest possible, but I don't have more time to polish it.)

```
(defn reduce-through
   [f & colls]
   (when-let [colls (seq (filter seq colls))]
     (cons (reduce f (map first colls))
           (apply reduce-through f (map rest colls)))))

(defn sum-up-levels
   [levels]
   (apply reduce-through + levels))
```

After having `levels` defined, it's easy to get the result in the form you need. Try it (a hint - use `tree-seq`.)

Comment: Yuri, thanks for taking the time to answer in such detail. I think I got the idea here. The first thing I'm planning to do is to change my tree representation from a map to a seq like this: '(1 (2 (4 (6)) 3 5) and then use tree-seq to build the missing functions (branch? and children).What do you think?

Comment: Yes, I think working with a sequence like this should be simpler. `branch?` and `children` are fairly trivial in this case. (You don't need `tree-seq` to build these functions, rather `tree-seq` can use them to turn a tree into a sequence, which will be then very simple to process.)

Comment: Thanks again. It worked very well using the data-structure I started with :-) But I got curious of how to write the children function using a tree represent as '(1 (2 (4 (6)) 3 5). For the first tree representation, the code looks like this: `(defn children
  [node]
  (filter (fn [[x, y]] (= node (:root y))) tree))`

Comment: Off the top of my head, you may use a list (or a sublist) to represent a branch node, then `branch?` is just `list?`, and `children` is just `rest`.

Comment: Of course in this case you would use `(levels a-list)` instead of `(levels 2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn children-depths [parents]
  (let [children ; let's first build an inverted index
        (reduce-kv (fn [children node {parent :root}]
                     (update children parent conj node))
          {} parents)
        depths (fn depths [node]
                 (if-some [nodes (children node)]
                   (into [(count nodes)]
                     ; pads and sums
                     (reduce #(map + (concat %1 (repeat 0)) (depths %2))
                       nil nodes))
                   []))] ; no descendants -> empty 
    (into {} (for [node (keys parents)] [node (depths node)]))))

=> (children-depths {1 {:root nil} 2 {:root 1} 3 {:root 1} 4 {:root 2} 5 {:root 1} 6 {:root 4}})
{1 [3 1 1], 2 [1 1], 3 [], 4 [1], 5 [], 6 []}
```

One obvious improvement would be to avoid recomputing depths of children.